# Use QProcess to create a child process, then set its screen position

Tags: qt

I need to launch another program from my code but I also need to set its screen position?
Is this possible using QT?
Very simple In principal but as usual extremely difficult in QT...

Comment: not possible unless the child process allows it through commandline args or you do some debug hooks

Comment: Thank you very much, definite answer.

Comment: Remember that Qt is a cross-platform framework. If you think it's "easy" on any particular platform, nobody is preventing you, from, you know, "just" doing it. Personally, I'd find doing almost anything using WINAPI or X11 to be extremely convoluted, but hey, it's just my opinion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by setting the dwX and dwY varibles In the STARTUPINFO struct and then setting dwFlags to STARTF_USEPOSITION.

Then call CreateProcess

Answer (score 0):

If the program you are calling allows it through the command line arguments then it is definitely possible.

in windows there is the option of providing the [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but that only works if the program uses `CW_USEDEFAULT` for its location

Otherwise you would need to use a debugger to hook into the relevant `setLocation` call and change the arguments, this is very hard without intimate knowledge of the program in question.

Comment: That wont do for this program, is this possible using the windows API?? I've tried using CreateProcess with STARTUPINFO to specify a location but it doesn't seem to make a difference, any suggestions on how this could actually be done??

Comment: @user3581328 So, you still claim that things are extremely difficult in Qt? :)